# Calculate an integral of an irrational function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions

How can I calculate this integral

$$\int \frac{dx}{(x^2+b)\sqrt{x^2-a}} $$

Without using the substitution $$x=\sqrt{a}\sec {u} $$

I guess I'm having some problems while using secant substitution so I wanted to know if there is any other possible way to solve the above integral . 
Any hint will be appreciated.
Thank you in return!

Comment: *Mathematica* gives:  $\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x \sqrt{-a-b}}{\sqrt{b} \sqrt{x^2-a}}\right)}{\sqrt{b}
   \sqrt{-a-b}}$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork how?

Comment: Through the substitution $x=\sqrt{a} \sec u$.

Comment: But I wanted another way of solving it without using this substitution

Comment: Don't know another method.

Comment: If a>0, b>0 CAS Maxima gives $$-\frac{\log{\left( \frac{b\, \sqrt{{{x}^{2}}-a}-\sqrt{{{b}^{2}}+a b} x}{b\, \sqrt{{{x}^{2}}-a}+\sqrt{{{b}^{2}}+a b} x}\right) }}{2 \sqrt{{{b}^{2}}+a b}}$$

Comment: Try $x=\sqrt{a}\cosh\log t$ and partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With $\ds{\quad x \equiv {t^{2} + a \over 2t}\quad}$ and
>   $\ds{\quad t = x - \root{x^{2} - a}}$:

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{\int{\dd x \over \pars{x^{2} + b}\root{x^{2} - a}}}} =
-\int{4t \over t^{4} + 2\pars{a + 2b}t^{2} + a^{2}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] \stackrel{y\ =\ t^{2}}{=}\,\,\,&
-2\int{\dd y \over y^{2} + 2\pars{a + 2b}y + a^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-2\int{\dd y \over \pars{y + a + 2b}^{2} + a^{2} - \pars{a + 2b}^{2}} =
-2\int{\dd y \over \pars{y + a + 2b}^{2} - 4b\pars{b - a}}
\end{align}

> At this point, the integration is an elementary one. What is the relation between $\ds{a\ \mbox{and}\ b}$ ?.

Comment: a and b are just random numbers , there's no specific relation between them.

Comment: @MathsSurvivor 0 k. It's fine.

Comment: thank you for your answer!

Comment: @MathsSurvivor $\displaystyle\Large \left({\bullet \qquad \bullet \atop \mid} \atop \mbox{You're welcome}\right)$